# How to reassign a string?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program which merges a lines from stdin and print only those sentences which are longer than 80 characters. The first found line works well - the later ones, however, are empty. I think that I am doing something wrong with the line
`current_sentence = malloc(sentence_len);`.

How can I reassign a string correctly?

**Code**

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# define BUFFERSIZE 100

char* merge_string(char *text[], int n){
    int i;
    char *result = malloc(BUFFERSIZE * n);

    for (i=0; i < n; i++){
        strcat(result, text[i]);

    }
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

    int i = 0;
    char *text[BUFFERSIZE];

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL){
        text[i] = strdup(buffer);
        i++;
        }
    char *sentence = merge_string(text, i);

    int sentence_len = strlen(sentence);
    int j = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    char *current_sentence = malloc(sentence_len);

    while (j < sentence_len){
        current_sentence[counter] = sentence[j];

        if (sentence[j] == '\n' && counter >= 80){
            printf(":::HIT:::%s\n\n\n", current_sentence);
            counter = 0;
            current_sentence = malloc(sentence_len);
            }
            else if (sentence[j] == '\n'){
                    puts("Resetting counter");
                    counter = 0;
            }
            j++; counter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
make 1_17; ./1_17 < example.txt
make: `1_17' is up to date.
Resetting counter
Resetting counter
:::HIT:::SHenri Cartier-Bresson (1908-2004) said "Your first 10,000 photographs are your        worst," but he shot more than one an hour.) 



Resetting counter
:::HIT:::


Resetting counter
:::HIT:::
```

Comment: But with regards to what you are trying to do: why don't you make BUFFERSIZE equal to 81, then the fgets will do most of the work for you.

Comment: @MrLister that would seem to be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not terminating `current_sentence` with a null character (`'\0'`). If you want `printf` to print the string properly, better make sure it is null-terminated.

By the way, there's no need for a second `malloc`. Reuse the memory allocated for `current_sentence` without re-allocating.

Also note that you're not freeing the allocated memory properly. You should be use a matching `free` call for each `malloc`. Perhaps this isn't a problem now, but it creates a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Your loop should look something like this:

```
while (j < sentence_len)
{
    current_sentence[counter] = sentence[j];
    if (sentence[j] == '\n')
    {
        if (counter >= 80)
        {
            current_sentence[counter + 1] = '\0'; // Make string null-terminated
            printf(":::HIT:::%s\n\n\n", current_sentence);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Resetting counter");
        }
        counter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
    j++;
}

free(current_sentence); // Free allocated memory
```

Then again, [as mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784462/how-to-reassign-a-string/19784560#comment29408436_19784462), you'd rather let `fgets` do the work for you indeed.

Comment: I suspect he's correct on the `j` loop; its looks to be just copying characters to the next sentence. but I think I know where the issue is. (I think).

Comment: @WhozCraig Hmm, you're right. Maybe the problem is with the null-termination.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *text[BUFFERSIZE];
```

should be

```
char text[BUFFERSIZE];
```

Comment: Guess again. The loop is a dead giveaway. the intention is to treat it as an array of pointers-to-string.